# What is an elegant way to create a "logic glue" of a serverless app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I need to implement the following logic:

1. PDF with several (unknown in advanced) pages is upload and saved to S3
2. Page images are extracted from the pdf via a lambda function and saved to S3.
3. Each image is analyzed by a lambda function (concurrently). The results are saved either to S3 or dynamo.
4. Once ALL the images has been analyzed, run a final single lambda that combine all of the results.

One of my main issue is how to get triggered when all the concurrent lambdas of step 3 has finished. 
What is the best, most elegant way to accomplish that?
I had suggestions to try using AWS step function, but it seems that the Parallel state can only have fixed number, known in advance branches.

Answer (score 2):

As you are already using Dynamodb in your solution, one possible solution I could think:

```
Step 2: 
        Extract Images and store total_count in Dynamodb
Step 3: 
       At the end of Lambda increment new column current_count
       if(current_count==total_count){ trigger Step 4 }
```

Comment: I've done something similar. But it is getting very quickly out of hand. sometimes the triggers and the states are spread all over the S3, dynamo DB and lambdas. No one central place for the flow logic. There must be a better way...

Comment: You could use an orchestration lambda (that listens to a bunch of topics so it knows the status of each pdf and each page, then works out what to do when it receives each event) which is a nicer way to understand the flow logic. But at the end of the day, you need a data store so you can check off each page, so you know when the entire pdf is completed.